# Garage Door Only Operates When Light Is Off

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

I've done all the digging I could on the internet and still can't fix the issue. I want to get a second opinion before I shell out $240 for a new garage door opener. Right now, I have an older Sears 139.53963SRT installed. So, my issue:

The opener will not open or close the door from a distance when the lights are on. If I hold the remote right next to where the antenna comes out, it will work. This leads me to think it's a RF interference issue.

The pad on the wall works regardless. So that rules out it being a sensor issue. There are no blink codes or anything like that.

It used to work fine, then one day it just stopped working normally. When I started looking into it, I noticed a bulb went out. I replaced them with LED bulbs for "garage door openers" and issue still persisted. After reading it could be a bulb issue, I got some incandescent 100W bulbs and still the issue persists. The whole push the light off and walk out jumping over the sensor so the light doesn't come back on is starting to get old lol.

I did install some hardwired cameras and there is some CAT6 cable running in the area above. But I don't think that would give off interference. I guess I could disconnect them and try. But I know for a fact the first one I installed, it still worked after the fact. It was months later before I ran a second one in that area.

I did install a motion activated sensor for the garage overhead lights. But I recall for certain that it still worked fine after the fact. I tried covering the sensor which is by the house entrance door with tin foil and issue still persisted. So, I don't think that is causing the RF interference if that is that case.

I read about an issue with capacitors on the control board thingy... but if I turn the opener lights off it still works fine, so I don't think it is that.

I have 3 of the remotes that came with the garage door opener, and 4 after market remotes. So it is not a remote or battery issue. (I have a lot of cars/bikes lol).

I have a Chamberlin garage door opener for one of the other doors and it works flawless.

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced!

Edit:

Tried removing bulbs/disconnecting sockets. Still no avail.

Comment: You've tried most things. What happens if you remove the bulb(s) from the opener? Does it still need the "lights off" to work if there's no bulb in there?

Comment: Tried that as well. Even completely disconnected the sockets. Still no avail.

Comment: Could it be that the lights are somehow interfering with the optical sensors around the door?

Comment: Did you try changing the CODE on the opener and main unit

Comment: `motion activated sensor ` work with ultrasound which could interfere with garage door RF

Comment: I had the exact same problem with model 139.53672SRT3.  The good news is some replacements have the same bolt holes as the original.   Much to my delight, the Chamberlin model I bought fit perfectly and now I can open and close my garage door from anywhere in the world!

Comment: It could be that one of your _neighbors_ has recently installed something that's generating RF interference with _your_ opener. If you're on good terms with the neighbors, now might be a good time to canvas the neighborhood to ask. If someone's installed something new, ask them to turn it off for a few minutes so you can test your opener. If that's the problem, well... at least you know and now you can negotiate.

Comment: You're long past the point of having spent more effort on this clunker than it's worth. Replacement seems like the best bet to me.

Comment: you broke the antenna, check inside for it

Answer (score 2):

The electronics change with age and if all remotes are behaving the same it is in the opener receiver. This starts to happen after about 15 years of use. This is normal. The parts are temperature sensitive and also drift with time. The light is mainly coincidental as you are changing capacitance (tuning) etc by being close to the receiver unless you are at the same point for each test. Easiest solution is get a new opener or a third party wireless remote.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the problem is internal to the opener. All the things you tried have no bearing on whether it will work with the remote unless the light is turned off. Even with no bulbs the circuit for the light can still be "on" which is why removing the bulbs makes no difference. It doesn't seem that you'll get it to work with the remote unless you can find a way to disable the "light switch" on the control board. It seems like you identified the problem. As a last resort disable and remove power to the cameras, motion sensors, light bulbs etc. make sure your vehicle is not near the garage (heard some vehicles can cause interference). Put a bulb in the opener and then try it with and without the light turned on. If it works with the light off and doesn't work with the light on then it's internal to the opener.

Answer (score 0):

`If I hold the remote right next to where the antenna comes out, it will work`

This would say it is a broken antenna, the pice of black wire hanging out, even if you have brand new battery in the remote, and cleaned the battery contacts.

Find a wire (18 or 22 gauge) and wrap a part of it around the black wire, and let it hang to extend the antenna by few inches.

This might not work if the antenna is broken inside (on the control board), so you need to inspect that (Look inside).

How does that interact with the lights mounted on the garage door opener, I do not know, but since you worked on it, it is possible the antenna got damaged.